# C# data comparison

Tags: c#, arrays

my task is to read data from two text files, store that data in two separate arrays, read how many of lines match, how many of the lines don't match, and display which specific lines don't match. I know a for loop would be better but I can't remember what to do for it. I'm not sure of where to go from here and if anyone knows anything that could help, help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Final_Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void grade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] A = new string[20];
            string[] B = new string[20];
            StreamReader ifile;
            StreamReader ifile2;
            ifile = File.OpenText("answerkey.txt");
            ifile2 = File.OpenText("response.txt");
            int correct = 0;
            int incorrect = 0;
            string str = "";
            string str2 = "";
            while (ifile.EndOfStream == false & ifile2.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                str = ifile.ReadLine();
                str2 = ifile2.ReadLine();
            }

            A[correct] = str;
            B[incorrect] = str2;

            if (A[0] == B[0])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[1] == B[1])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[2] == B[2])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[3] == B[3])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[4] == B[4])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[5] == B[5])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[6] == B[6])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[7] == B[7])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[8] == B[8])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[9] == B[9])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[10] == B[10])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[11] == B[11])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[12] == B[12])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[13] == B[13])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[14] == B[14])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[15] == B[15])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[16] == B[16])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[17] == B[17])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[18] == B[18])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (A[19] == B[19])

            {
                correct++;
            }
            else

            {
                incorrect++;
            }

            if (correct >= 14)
            {
                passfail.Text = "Passed";
            }
            else
            {
                passfail.Text = "Failed";
            }

            string[] result = File.ReadAllLines("answerkey.txt");

            correctbox.Text = correct.ToString();
            incorrectbox.Text = incorrect.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `while` loop, you keep overwriting `str` and `str2` on each iteration instead of storing the read data in the arrays `A` and `B`.

Comment: Is there a relationship between the two collections of strings. For example, if each collection has 10 elements, will you be doing 10 comparisons or 100

Comment: Are you asking how to write a for loop? What research have you done so far? I would expect such information to be very easy to find if you do some searching.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few pointers:

1. Use [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0) to read the files.
2. Write a `for` loop that iterates over the answer file lines and compare A[i] to B[i] and update `correct` and `incorrect`.
3. Think of a case where the responses file has less lines than the answers file.